# Where to start on fixing a locations module not accurately displaying on a gmap with views

Tags: views, google-maps

I have been having problems with my locations module displaying points on a gmap using views. I have a profile 2 profile that has a locations field on it to store locations. I collect that data using a views to display it on a gmap. But this all works.

The problem I am having is the location points are in most cases not at all accurate or do not show at all. I have a list of 92 countries that are not working correctly. Some smaller countries I could care less about but ones like Barbados and Finland are not working.

[image: Barbados in Germany]

I cannot figure out how to start on fixing this issue. It may be a locations.xx.inc problem, or a geocoding problem or a gmap problem. I do not know where to start.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: http://imgur.com/HrPvlns Here is an example. The lat and long are completely incorrect for Barbados.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, pin is rendered at the good coordinates. So the bug is in the Country to coordinates relationship data. You need to look in your database and find a table with this data. Probably, to avoid name collisions, table will be prefixed with module name.

When you have it, just update it with coordinates of capital cities, for example from Wikipedia.

Comment: Where would this data base be? Under myphpadmin? Thank you. I wouldn't have thought to look in the database like this.

Comment: @Greg - it's either in your Drupal database, or it's pulled from external server. If it's not the first case, you need to read module's code.

Comment: That does work using the locations database, but it only changes one instance of it. More can be created at the original wrong coordinates.

Comment: @Greg you asked where to start. Don't expect me to go and do it all for you. If you want that, post usual bugreport.

Comment: No no, don't get me wrong, I appreciate your ideas

Comment: @Greg Sorry, It was a hard day for me and I might have been less patient and understanding than I should.

Comment: Dont worry. I understand. This problem is getting me frustrated. I feel you haha

Comment: Well I have concluded that locations is confusing country codes and province codes. IE, BB should be Barbados, but its showing up as Brandenburg Germany. I have no idea how to fix it but I have progress!